# Python: Downloading a large file to a local path and setting custom http headers

Tags: python, http, download, urllib2, urllib

I am looking to download a file from a http url to a local file. The file is large enough that I want to download it and save it chunks rather than `read()` and `write()` the whole file as a single giant string.

The interface of `urllib.urlretrieve` is essentially what I want. However, I cannot see a way to set request headers when downloading via  `urllib.urlretrieve`, which is something I need to do.

If I use `urllib2`, I can set request headers via its `Request` object. However, I don't see an API in `urllib2` to download a file directly to a path on disk like `urlretrieve`. It seems that instead I will have to use a loop to iterate over the returned data in chunks, writing them to a file myself and checking when we are done.

What would be the best way to build a function that works like `urllib.urlretrieve` but allows request headers to be passed in?

Comment: What's wrong with looping over chunks of returned data, out of curiosity?

Comment: How do I know when to stop? read() returning the empty string doesn't necessarily mean the end (as it does for files) because the data might still be trickling in. I can rely on the content-length header, but it feels like a mechanism for doing this should already exist somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

What is the harm in writing your own function using urllib2?

```
import os
import sys
import urllib2

def urlretrieve(urlfile, fpath):
    chunk = 4096
    f = open(fpath, "w")
    while 1:
        data = urlfile.read(chunk)
        if not data:
            print "done."
            break
        f.write(data)
        print "Read %s bytes"%len(data)
```

and using request object to set headers

```
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.google.com")
request.add_header('User-agent', 'Chrome XXX')
urlretrieve(urllib2.urlopen(request), "/tmp/del.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use urllib and urlretrieve, subclass `urllib.URLopener` and use its `addheader()` method to adjust the headers (ie: `addheader('Accept', 'sound/basic')`, which I'm pulling from the docstring for urllib.addheader).

To install your URLopener for use by urllib, see the example in the [urllib._urlopener](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) section of the docs (note the underscore):

```
import urllib

class MyURLopener(urllib.URLopener):
    pass # your override here, perhaps to __init__

urllib._urlopener = MyURLopener
```

However, you'll be pleased to hear wrt your comment to the question comments, reading an empty string from `read()` is indeed the signal to stop. This is how urlretrieve handles when to stop, for example. TCP/IP and sockets abstract the reading process, blocking waiting for additional data unless the connection on the other end is EOF and closed, in which case read()ing from connection returns an empty string. An empty string means there is no data trickling in... you don't have to worry about ordered packet re-assembly as that has all been handled for you. If that's your concern for urllib2, I think you can safely use it.

Comment: The above threw a TypeError: must be type, not classob (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698614/super-raises-typeerror-must-be-type-not-classobj-for-new-style-class ) and from the API docs it looks like brackets should be added: urllib._urlopener = MyURLopener()