# super() raises "TypeError: must be type, not classobj" for new-style class

Tags: python, superclass, super, typeerror

The following use of `super()` raises a TypeError: why?

```
>>> from  HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> class TextParser(HTMLParser):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(TextParser, self).__init__()
...         self.all_data = []
...         
>>> TextParser()
(...)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

There is a similar question on StackOverflow: [Python super() raises TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489269/python-super-raises-typeerror-why), where the error is explained by the fact that the user class is not a new-style class.  However, the class above is a new-style class, as it inherits from `object`:

```
>>> isinstance(HTMLParser(), object)
True
```

What am I missing? How can I use `super()`, here?

Using `HTMLParser.__init__(self)` instead of `super(TextParser, self).__init__()` would work, but I would like to understand the TypeError.

PS: Joachim pointed out that being a new-style-class instance is not equivalent to being an `object`. I read the opposite many times, hence my confusion (example of new-style class instance test based on `object` instance test: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2655651/3).

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer. I wonder why 2.7's `super.__doc__` doesn't mention anything about old vs new style!

Comment: Thanks. :) Docstrings typically contain less information than the full, HTML version of the documentation. The fact that `super()` works only for new-style classes (and objects) is mentioned in the HTML doc (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python super() raises TypeError ! Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489269/python-super-raises-typeerror-why)

Comment: This is not a duplicate (see the updated question, and the accepted answer).

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Alright, it's the usual "`super()` cannot be used with an old-style class".

However, the important point is that **the correct test** for "is this a new-style **instance** (i.e. object)?" is

```
>>> class OldStyle: pass
>>> instance = OldStyle()
>>> issubclass(instance.__class__, object)
False
```

and not (as in the question):

```
>>> isinstance(instance, object)
True
```

For **classes**, the correct "is this a new-style class" test is:

```
>>> issubclass(OldStyle, object)  # OldStyle is not a new-style class
False
>>> issubclass(int, object)  # int is a new-style class
True
```

The **crucial point** is that with old-style classes, the *class* of an instance and its *type* are distinct. Here, `OldStyle().__class__` is `OldStyle`, which does not inherit from `object`, while `type(OldStyle())` is the `instance` type, which *does* inherit from `object`.  Basically, an old-style class just creates objects of type `instance` (whereas a new-style class creates objects whose type is the class itself). This is probably why the instance `OldStyle()` is an `object`: its `type()` inherits from `object` (the fact that  its class does *not* inherit from `object` does not count: old-style classes merely construct new objects of type `instance`). Partial reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699961/42973.

PS: The difference between a new-style class and an old-style one can also be seen with:

```
>>> type(OldStyle)  # OldStyle creates objects but is not itself a type
classobj
>>> isinstance(OldStyle, type)
False
>>> type(int)  # A new-style class is a type
type
```

(old-style classes are *not* types, so they cannot be the type of their instances).

Comment: And this is one of the reasons we now have Python 3.

Comment: BTW: `(Oldstyle().__class__ is Oldstyle)` is `True`

Comment: @Tino: indeed, but the point of `OldStyle().__class__` is to show how to test whether an *object* (`OldStyle()`) comes from an old-style class. With only new-style classes in mind, one might be tempted to do the test with `isinstance(OldStyle(), object)` instead.

Comment: It is preposterous how much of the python standard library *still* in 2.7.x doesn't inherit from `object`, thus screwing you by proxy.

Comment: @NickBastin - this is not a coincidence. It's all in order to push everybody into Python 3. Where "everything is fine already." But - caveat emptor - it's only bait and switch.

Comment: **Today I learned that Python 2 is insanity.** I hit this today, when `UserDict` behaved astonishingly insanely under Python 2.7. The failure to convert standard Python 2.7 old-style classes to new-style significantly complicates middleware attempting to support both Python 2.7 and 3. What were they thinking? (_They weren't, clearly._)

Answer (score 212):

super() can be used only in the new-style classes, which means the root class needs to inherit from the 'object' class.

For example, the top class need to be like this:

```py
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ....
```

not

```py
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        ....
```

So, the solution is that call the parent's **init** method directly, like this way:

```py
class TextParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.all_data = []
```

Comment: For me, I had to do this: HTMLParser.__init__(self)

I am curious as to if your last example worked?

Comment: The question is about *why* you *have* to do this (see the first PS).

Comment: @EOL What do mean? jeffp just pointed out that the code given in this answer is wrong due to lack of `self` parameter in `HTMLParser.__init__()` call.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: Sorry, my remark was about LittleQ's answer, not about jeffp's (good) point.

Comment: @jeffp sorry, it's a typo, I just type it out on SO but haven't test it, my fault. thanks for correcting

Comment: @EOL, true, I didn't notice that PS.

Comment: Upvote for a fix that works with existing code, such as logging.Formatter in python2.6

Answer (score 29):

You can also use `class TextParser(HTMLParser, object):`. This makes `TextParser` a *new-style* class, and `super()` can be used.

Comment: An upvote from me, as adding the inheritance from object is a good idea. (That said, this answer does not address the issue of understanding the TypeError of the question.)

Answer (score 25):

The problem is that `super` needs an `object` as an ancestor:

```
>>> class oldstyle:
...     def __init__(self): self.os = True

>>> class myclass(oldstyle):
...     def __init__(self): super(myclass, self).__init__()

>>> myclass()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

On closer examination one finds:

```
>>> type(myclass)
classobj
```

But:

```
>>> class newstyle(object): pass

>>> type(newstyle)
type
```

---

So the solution to your problem would be to inherit from object as well as from HTMLParser.
But make sure object comes last in the classes MRO:

```
>>> class myclass(oldstyle, object):
...     def __init__(self): super(myclass, self).__init__()

>>> myclass().os
True
```

Comment: Valid points, but they are already in previous answers. Also, instead of checking `type(myclass)`, what matters is whether `myclass` inherit from object (i.e. whether `isinstance(myclass, object)` is true—it is false).

Answer (score 17):

If you look at the inheritance tree (in version 2.6), `HTMLParser` inherits from `SGMLParser` which inherits from `ParserBase` which *doesn't* inherits from `object`. I.e. HTMLParser is an old-style class.

About your checking with `isinstance`, I did a quick test in ipython:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: isinstance(A, object)
Out[2]: True
```

Even if a class is old-style class, it's still an instance of `object`.

Comment: I believe that the correct test should be `isinstance(A(), object)`, not `isinstance(A, object)`, no?  With the latter, you are testing whether the *class* `A` is an `object`, whereas the question is whether *instances* of `A` are an `object`, right?

Comment: PS: the best test seems to be `issubclass(HTMLParser, object)`, which returns False.

Answer (score 5):

the correct way to do will be as following in the old-style classes which doesn't inherit from 'object'

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return "Hi there"

class B(A):
    def foo(self, name):
        return A.foo(self) + name
```

Comment: In the question, this method is already mentioned: the problem is to *understand* why an error message was produced, not to make it go away (in particular in this way).

Comment: Besides, this solution will not work in the case that we want a call an instance of the class `A` that stores an state.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW and though I'm no Python guru I got by with this

```
>>> class TextParser(HTMLParser):
...    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
...        if tag == "b":
...            self.all_data.append("bold")
...        else:
...            self.all_data.append("other")
...     
...         
>>> p = TextParser()
>>> p.all_data = []
>>> p.feed(text)
>>> print p.all_data
(...)
```

Just got me the parse results back as needed.