# Reading csv header white space and case insensitive

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Is there a possibility to read the header of a CSV file white space and case insensitive? As for now I use `csv.dictreader` like this:

```
import csv
csvDict = csv.DictReader(open('csv-file.csv', 'rU'))

# determine column_A name
if 'column_A' in csvDict.fieldnames:
    column_A = 'column_A'
elif ' column_A' in csvDict.fieldnames:
    # extra space
    column_A = ' column_A'
elif 'Column_A' in csvDict.fieldnames:
    # capital A
    column_A = 'Column_A'

# get column_A data
for lineDict in csvDict:
    print(lineDict[column_A])
```

As you can see from the code, my csv files sometimes differ in extra white space or capital letters, for example

- "column_A"
- " column_A"
- "Column_A"
- " Column_A"
- ...

I want to use something like this:

```
    column_A = ' Column_A'.strip().lower()
    print(lineDict[column_A])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you also want to access the dictionary with automatically strip() and lower() the query, have a look at my fully working code example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12970460/1251007

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about override `DictReader.fieldnames` property?

```
class MyDictReader(DictReader):

    @property
    def fieldnames(self):
        return [field.strip().lower() for field in super(MyDictReader, self).fieldnames]
```

Comment: If you try this in Python 2 it won't work because csv.DictReader is a classic-style class and you can't use `super` in classic-style, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698614/super-raises-typeerror-must-be-type-not-classobj-for-new-style-class

Answer (score 16):

You can redefine `reader.fieldnames`:

```
import csv
import io

content = '''column_A " column_B"
1 2'''
reader = csv.DictReader(io.BytesIO(content), delimiter = ' ')
reader.fieldnames = [field.strip().lower() for field in reader.fieldnames]
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```

yields

```
{'column_b': '2', 'column_a': '1'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your code is more readable/usable for beginners. However, I chose "Defuz" answer as the correct one, as it is more pythonic and can be reused easier.