# Accessing csv header white space and case insensitive

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm overriding the `csv.Dictreader.fieldnames` property like the following to read all headers from csv files without white space and in lower case.

```
import csv
class MyDictReader(csv.DictReader):

    @property
    def fieldnames(self):
        return [field.strip().lower() for field in super(MyDictReader, self).fieldnames]
```

Now my question is, how can I access the fieldnames with automatically `strip()` and `lower()` the query?

This is, how I do it manually:

```
csvDict = MyDictReader(open('csv-file.csv', 'rU'))

for lineDict in csvDict:
    query = ' Column_A'.strip().lower()
    print(lineDict[query])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Pedro Romano's suggestion I coded the following example.

```
import csv

class DictReaderInsensitive(csv.DictReader):
    # This class overrides the csv.fieldnames property.
    # All fieldnames are without white space and in lower case

    @property
    def fieldnames(self):
        return [field.strip().lower() for field in super(DictReaderInsensitive, self).fieldnames]

    def __next__(self):
        # get the result from the original __next__, but store it in DictInsensitive

        dInsensitive = DictInsensitive()
        dOriginal = super(DictReaderInsensitive, self).__next__()

        # store all pairs from the old dict in the new, custom one
        for key, value in dOriginal.items():
            dInsensitive[key] = value

        return dInsensitive

class DictInsensitive(dict):
    # This class overrides the __getitem__ method to automatically strip() and lower() the input key

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key.strip().lower())
```

For a file containing headers like

- "column_A"
- " column_A"
- "Column_A"
- " Column_A"
- ...

you can access the columns like this:

```
csvDict = DictReaderInsensitive(open('csv-file.csv', 'rU'))

for lineDict in csvDict:
    print(lineDict[' Column_A']) # or
    print(lineDict['Column_A']) # or
    print(lineDict[' column_a']) # all returns the same
```

Comment: When I try to run this I get the following error:
return [field.strip().lower() for field in super(MyDictReader, self).fieldnames]   
TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Comment: @PrestonDocks: I learned from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489269/python-super-raises-typeerror-why) that `super` behaves different in Python2 and Python3. The code should work with **Python3**. Did you try that?

Comment: The problem is that DictReader is an "old style" class in Python2, and is "new style" in Python3. You can fix this by inheriting from object:

`DictReaderInsensitive(csv.DictReader, object ):`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it in two steps:

1. Create your `dict` specialisation with a `__getitem__` method that applies the `.strip().lower()` to the its `key` parameter.
2. Override `__next__` on your `MyDictReader` specialised class to return one of your special dictionaries initialised with the dictionary returned by the `csv.DictReader` superclass's `__next__` method.