# Python dictreader - How to make CSV column names lowercase?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file with the column names in upper case. I am reading the data using csv.dictreader but need the column names in lowercase.

I found this code here [Accessing csv header white space and case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956930/accessing-csv-header-white-space-and-case-insensitive)

```
    import csv

class DictReaderInsensitive(csv.DictReader):
    # This class overrides the csv.fieldnames property.
    # All fieldnames are without white space and in lower case

    @property
    def fieldnames(self):
        return [field.strip().lower() for field in super(DictReaderInsensitive, self).fieldnames]

    def __next__(self):
        # get the result from the original __next__, but store it in DictInsensitive

        dInsensitive = DictInsensitive()
        dOriginal = super(DictReaderInsensitive, self).__next__()

        # store all pairs from the old dict in the new, custom one
        for key, value in dOriginal.items():
            dInsensitive[key] = value

        return dInsensitive

class DictInsensitive(dict):
    # This class overrides the __getitem__ method to automatically strip() and lower() the input key

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key.strip().lower())
```

My problem is that when I run this with

```
datafile = open(self.ifs_data_file,'rU')
        csvDict = DictReaderInsensitive(datafile)
        for row in csvDict:
            print row
            #self.db.ifs_data.insert(**row)
            #self.db.commit()
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Development\python\supplier_review\supplier_review.py", line 239, in update_ifs_data
    for row in csvDict:
  File "D:\Python27_5\lib\csv.py", line 103, in next
    self.fieldnames
  File "D:\Development\python\supplier_review\supplier_review.py", line 288, in fieldnames
    return [field.strip().lower() for field in super(DictReaderInsensitive, self).fieldnames]
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could lowercase the first line of the file before passing it to `DictReader`:

```
import csv
import itertools

def lower_first(iterator):
    return itertools.chain([next(iterator).lower()], iterator)

with open(ifs_data_file, 'rU') as datafile:
    csvDict = csv.DictReader(lower_first(datafile))
    for row in csvDict:
        print row
```

Comment: Four years later, this is still a useful, easy to implement technique.

Answer (score 9):

`DictReader` is an old-style object, so `super()` doesn't work at all here. You need to directly access the `property` object in the parent class. In Python 2, you want to override the `.next()` method, not `.__next__()`:

```
class DictReaderInsensitive(csv.DictReader):
    # This class overrides the csv.fieldnames property.
    # All fieldnames are without white space and in lower case

    @property
    def fieldnames(self):
        return [field.strip().lower() for field in csv.DictReader.fieldnames.fget(self)]

    def next(self):
        return DictInsensitive(csv.DictReader.next(self))
```

Demo:

```
>>> example = '''\
... foo,Bar,BAZ
... 42,3.14159,Hello world!'''.splitlines()
>>> csvDict = DictReaderInsensitive(example)
>>> row = next(csvDict)
>>> print row
{'bar': '3.14159', 'foo': '42', 'baz': 'Hello world!'}
>>> row['BAZ']
'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your suggestions. I found another way around this problem but to be honest I cant remember what it was. I did try Martijn's but it did not work for me.

Comment: I'm sorry my solution did not work for you; had you  let me know what problems you encountered I could perhaps have helped you overcome them. As you can see from my answer I tested the code for you.

Answer (score 7):

For a much simpler approach, you can simply update the DictReader.fieldnames attribute before accessing your dictionary, as in:

```
>>> f = open('example-x-y-time.csv', 'rb')
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(f)
>>> reader.fieldnames
['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Date']
>>> print next(reader)
{'Latitude': '44.8982391', 'Date': '2004-07-12', 'Longitude': '-117.7791061'}
>>> reader.fieldnames = [name.lower() for name in reader.fieldnames]
>>> print next(reader)
{'latitude': '44.6637001', 'date': '1964-04-03', 'longitude': '-123.5997009'}
```