# python how to trim trailing spaces in csv DictReader keys

Tags: python

I am using python (2.6) csv DictReader. My input file has a header line where the column names have trailing spaces:

```
colname1,      colname2     ,col3, etc.
XX, YY, ZZ
```

The returned dict object has key() = `['colname1', 'colname2     ', 'col3']`

Is there an option to trim leading and trailing spaces from the keys?

--edit

The problem arises in processing by key names:

```
with open(fname) as f:
   r = csv.DictReader(f)
   for row in r:
      print "processing", r["column1"], r["column2"]
```

The files are database dumps. And the dump program is way too smart - it adjust the output column width depending on data -- which means different sets of selects are going to have different column width and different key lengths. Sometimes I must use `r['column2    ']` and sometimes pad or reduce spaces. ouch!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just read the first line manually and pass it along to the `DictReader`.

```
with open('file.csv') as fh:
    header = [h.strip() for h in fh.next().split(',')]
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=header)
```

Comment: I wish this were an option in csv.DictReader. (is there a place to express such wishlists?)

Comment: You could try requesting the feature but chances are they won't add it. To be fair, your csv is broken ;)

Comment: yes that CSV is *unusual* but it is a database dump and each vendor has its personality. But I know the outcome of not asking :) Where does one ask?

Comment: Doesn't work in python 3, FWIW. What does, though is [redefining `reader.fieldnames`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934129/588437).

Comment: If I just want to remove the whitespace from the header and save the file...how can I archieve this?

Comment: It comes down to the same method except writing all output to a temporary file and renaming that temporary file to the original filename when it's done writing.

Comment: It will split the single header with commas to several

Comment: I'd also like to auto strip leading and trailing spaces from the _values_.

Comment: @NeilG If there's a space after every comma/semicolon (i.e. `, `) than you could change the delimiter to that. For stripping all whitespace from each value I would recommend wrapping `self.reader` since it returns an iterable of values: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/547e8827e677c675274da0ca1134fc6c4a971c9a/Lib/csv.py#L112-L134
Perhaps this can work? `def stripping_reader(reader): for row in reader: yield from map(str.strip, row)`

Comment: Thanks, @Wolph. The wrapper is a good suggestion. As usual, the whitespace is inconsistent so a fixed delimiter is not going to cut it (excuse the pun). In this event I moved the `strip` call to my first data processing step. I think as Pythonistas we often expect everything to be so clean and seamless we're almost ready to create more boilerplate just so we can say we hid the activity in a sub-module, but actually Python is so compact anyway that it's just an extra line, or in this case, just an extra call in an expression somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

You need to register a custom dialect in the csv module

```
csv.register_dialect('MyDialect', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator='\n', strict=True)
```

then use the dialect when creating the DictReader:

```
my_reader = csv.DictReader(trip_file, dialect='MyDialect')
```

Here's all the [Dialect Options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters)

Comment: this only removes leading whitespace, but there's no option for trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

Python3 version

```py
with open('file.csv') as fh:
    header = [h.strip() for h in fh.readline().split(',')]
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=header)
```

Answer (score 3):

Following in the vein of other answers, but why not use the CSV reader for that header row?

```py
header = [h.strip() for h in next(csv.reader(f))]
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=header)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the csv to read the header, It can contain quotes or escaped characters.
Also, you need to consume it from the same IO so the header will be not consumed as a row.

```
data = io.StringIO(csv_file.read().decode('utf-8'))
data_header = io.StringIO(data.readline())
header = [h.strip() for h in next(csv.reader(data_header))]
reader = csv.DictReader(data, fieldnames=header)
```