# Python: how to add an empty list in derived class

Tags: python, class, member, derived

Yes I'm a new bee to python. this is my first program after studying it.

this is a HTML crawler, to fetch all the mp3 files on a certain site.

I have done the job, but confused with 2 problems, here is what I have been through:

I tried to add a class derive from HTMLParser.

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        pass
```

it worked. so I tried to add a list member to remember every URL it meets.

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    urlList = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        pass
```

but soon I discovered that it's like a "static" class member in C++.

in python we do not need to declare a member before using.

so the code goes to:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if something:
            self.urlList.append(target)
```

but the python pop some error when runing it, says MyHTMLParser has no attributes of "urlList".

I'm confused, why python would not add it automatically?

so I added the "initialization" (and "declaration" in my mind) like this:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.urllist = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if something:
            self.urlList.append(target)
```

but in this form, the python told me some error about the HTMLParser, I found it's because that I didn't call the parent **init**().

so the code goes to:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        #DO PARENT CLASS INIT
        self.urllist = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if something:
            self.urlList.append(target)
```

the #DO PARENT CLASS INIT, I found two ways listed below.

one is stupid, I went to the HTMLParser lib and found what it did in the **init**() and copied:

```
self.reset() #it's what HTMLParser did in __init__()
```

or

```
HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
```

I know it's workable but ugly, so my question is:

1, the elegant way to call the parent init() method when overriding it.

2, how to add a list member without "declaration" like I listed in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke parent class method you just use `super(<currentClass>, self).method(<parent method arguments>)`. In your case it would be something like

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        #python 3
        super(MyHTMLParser, self).__init()
        # in python 2 HTMLParser is an old-style class, so the above won't work
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
```

Refer to [`super` manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

As of "declaration" - looks like you misundestood what "declaration" means in python. Python does not automatically create stuff when you try to *read* something. So, by doing

```
self.my_urllist = []
```

you just tell it to create an empty list and store it at `my_urllist` class member. It's not "declaration", but just an assingment. However,

```
self.my_urllist.append(target)
```

Reads as "please *read* `self.my_urllist` than try to *invoke* `append` method on whatever you have read". Two things can go wrong here: (1) `self.my_urllist` does not exist; (2) `self.my_urllist` does not have `append` method.

So, in order to make it work, you must ensure that before you do `self.my_urllist.append` you actually have `self.my_urllist` member and it is a list. Pythonic way to do it is to create `my_urllist` in `__init__` and assign it some sensible value (empty list in your case).

If you absolutely don't want to override `__init__` you can go with technique known as *lazy initialization", like so:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    @property
    def my_urllist(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_my_urllist'):
             self._my_urllist = []
        return self._my_urllist
```

[`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) is a decorator that makes method look like attribute. But anyway, some object attribute (`_my_urllist`) is created and initialized, it's just delayed until you really need it.

Comment: " Python does not automatically create stuff when you try to read something. " that's very helpful, thank you.

Comment: in fact i tried to use the super(MyHTMLParser, self).__init__() but the result is an error "TypeError: must be type, not classobj"

Comment: @Ethansong definitely related to to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698614/super-raises-typeerror-must-be-type-not-classobj-for-new-style-class

Comment: Python 2.7.8(default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48)

Answer (score 0):

Your second way is the right way to do it. Its not ugly.

As an alternative you can do:

```
super(MyHTMLParser, self).__init__()
```

You are doing everything the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Never copy the parent method's code. The two standard options to call the parent's `__init__` are

```
HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
```

and

```
super(MyHTMLParser, self).__init__()
```

If you're using Python 3, the second option has been simplified to

```
super().__init__()
```

There's no way to avoid the `self.my_urllist = []` step. After all, Python needs *some* way to tell that this attribute is supposed to be a list.