# Python class inside subclass inheriting from class inside parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass

The title is pretty much self explanatory, but I think this is better explained with an example.

```
class Dog():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_color(self):
        return body_color()

    class personality_1():

        def get_happiness(self):
            return happiness_with_owner()

        def get_sadness(self):
            return sadness()
        ## A lot more personality methods here


class SocialDog(Dog):

    # Override regular method
    def get_color(self):
        return face_color()

    # I want to override the personality 1 class but not completely, just one method
    class personality_2(>>>How to inherit from personality_1?<<<):
        # Now, I would like to override just one method of personality 1:
        def get_happiness(self):
        return happiness_with_others()
```

Hopefully the logic is correct. I was trying to use super() with no success. Hopefully I can find a solution without using an explicit call to the parent class.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inherit from the class you specified, according to the code you provided, all that is required is to define the class `personality_2` like this:

```
class SocialDog(Dog):
  #...
    class personality_2(Dog.personality_1):
      #...
```

Now, as for your problem when trying to use `super()`, this might be because your base classes of `Dog` and `Dog.personality_1` do not inherit from the python default class `object` which is required in order to use the `super()` method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9698750/2175939) answer for details. If that is what you are after, all you need to do is modify your class declarations for `Dog` and `Dog.personality_1` (or whatever they ultimately derive from) to the following:

```
class Dog(object):
  #...
  class personality_1(object):
    #...
```

Then you can treat `SocialDog.personality_2` just like any other subclass. If you are using python 2, remember when using `super()` that you need to use the fully qualified name:

```
super(SocialDog.personality_2, self).super_class_method()
super(SocialDog.personality_2, self).super_class_field
```

Comment: Looks like I was still typing mine when you posted this.  Good catch on the Python 2 inherit-from-object, by the way...  I'm used to Python 3.

Comment: Thanks @Sam, I think this answer the original question directly. However, Kevin J. Chase confirmed my original suspicion that the logic could be re-arranged. Would you also agree with that? The thing is I have multiple animals (gods, cows etc) with very different personalities each, so the reason I nested those classes was so that they wouldn't pollute the outer space with 2 classes for each animal.

Comment: @chrisfromlocalgroup:  It depends on how dependent personalities are on animals, and how many there are.  You might only need a handful of personalities to handle dozens of animals.  (Is an `AngryPersonality` inside a `Dog` _that_ much different when it's inside a `Cow` or `Snake`?)  That said, The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work is to make `AngryDog` a subclass of `Dog` with a more emphatic `get_madder` method.  Create and use a few of these classes, and it should quickly become clear if you're repeating lots of methods that should go into a separate `Personality` class.

Answer (score 1):

Use the name of the outer class to reach the inner class:

```
class SocialDog(Dog):
    class personality_2(Dog.personality_1):
        # ...
```

That said, this is a very weird thing you're doing, hiding the personality classes inside the dog classes, then using them *outside*...

If a personality is *that* tightly coupled to a specific class like `Dog` or `SocialDog`, what makes `personality_2` think it's safe to mess with the behaviour of `personality_1`?  In fact, the personality methods should probably be `Dog` or `SocialDog` methods instead.

Or, if it doesn't really matter which dog gets which personality, why not leave the personality classes up at the module level, where they can be instantiated and inherited like any other class?  Your various `Dog`-derived classes would then take an optional `personality` argument when created:

```
class WolfPersonality(DogPersonality):
    # ...

class Wolf(Dog):
    def __init__(self, personality=None):
        if personality is None:
            personality = WolfPersonality()
        self.personality = personality
        # ...

# Later...
wolf = Wolf()
wolf_puppy = Wolf(FriendlyDogPersonality())
```