# Python call super constructor

Tags: python, constructor, super

im working with the module HTMLParser and want to make a subclass. But i am unable to call the super constructor, what am i doing wrong ?

```
class CustomParser(HTMLParser):

def __init__(self):
    super(CustomParser, self).__init__()
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Marc\Phyton\rafafafaf\src\test.py", line 20, in <module>
C = CustomParser()
File "C:\Users\Marc\Phyton\rafafafaf\src\test.py", line 17, in __init__
super(CustomParser, self).__init__()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, `HTMLParser` is an old-style-class (type 'classobj'), and as such does not support collaborative `super()` call. The correct way to call the parent's methods from subclass is direct class access, ie:

```
class CustomParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class CustomParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
```

Or this:

```
class CustomParser(HTMLParser, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomParser, self).__init__(self)
```

Details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9719731/320104

Comment: edited, please verify