# Initialize .Net List in IronPython

Tags: ironpython

I am trying to initialize a .net of custom class objects as follows:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List

class EmployeeTree:

    def getEmployeeFirstName(self):
        return self.EmployeeFirstName
    def setEmployeeFirstName(self, firstName):
        self.EmployeeFirstName = firstName.strip()

    def getEmployeeLastName(self):
        return self.EmployeeLastName
    def setEmployeeLastName(self, lastName):
        self.EmployeeLastName = lastName.strip()

    def getEmployeeNumber(self):
        return self.EmployeeNumber
    def setEmployeeNumber(self, empNumber):
        self.EmployeeNumber = empNumber.strip()

    def __init__(self):
        self.EmployeeFirstName = ''
        self.EmployeeLastName = ''
        self.EmployeeNumber = ''
```

Later in the code I try to create a list of EmployeeTree objects

```
EmployeeTreeList = List[EmployeeTree]()
```

When I try to create the EmployeeTreeList I get the following error:

> expected Array[Type], got classobj

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not entire sure why this works because I'm not incredibly experienced, so maybe someone else can explain it. Try using class inheretance: `class EmployeeTree(object):` I was able to get it working like that.

Comment: Go check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698614/super-raises-typeerror-must-be-type-not-classobj-for-new-style-class

Comment: The `class EmployeeTree(object)` did the trick, Thanks!