# .NET List initialization in IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have a question about IronPython. I want to initialize List object from System.Collections.Generic in IronPython and use as a generic parameter my own written IronPython class. 
But then I get an error:

> expected Array[Type], got classobj

[image: Code snippet]

Can anyone provide me with some help? Where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd call this question a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573586/3775798), but that other question does not have any answers.

Answer (score 3):

To work around this issue, i use `object` instead of the class type, maybe not the best way to check the type...

```
list1 = List[object]()
```

Your syntax works if the `FirstClass` [inherits from a C# type](https://github.com/PMoureu/iph/blob/85a604ace227a4d20b5f8d0b718cde35959127b3/iph/core/modelview.py#L31)  or [builtins](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#net-arrays), but custom Python Class throw this error.

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use new style class on `FirstClass` to avoid this error and keep the right type checking in your array :

```
class First(object):
        i = 0
```