# PyPa setup.py test scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-packaging

I'm attempting to follow the advice and structure written in the [python packaging docs](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/). In the setup function you can specify dependencies for tests with `tests_require`. And you can run scripts on install just by specifying `scripts`. But can I have a script that is only run in the case of a setup for testing?

---

edit: Important parts of my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
# To use a consistent encoding
from codecs import open
from os import path
import subprocess
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.test import test

class setupTestRequirements(test, object):
    def run_script(self):
        cmd = ['bash', 'bin/test_dnf_requirements.sh']
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        ret = p.communicate()
        print(ret[0])

    def run(self):
        self.run_script()
        super(setupTestRequirements, self).run()

...
setup(
    ...
    scripts=['bin/functional_dnf_requirements.sh'],
    install_requires=['jira', 'PyYAML'],
    tests_require=['flake8', 'autopep8', 'mock'],

    cmdclass={'test': setupTestRequirements}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not mean the files in `scripts` will be executed on package installation. The keyword `scripts` is used to mark python files in your package that are intended to run as standalone programs after package installation (maybe the name is a bit misleading). Example: you have a file `spam` with the content:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('eggs!')
```

If you mark this file as script by adding it to the `scripts` in your `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    scripts=['spam'],
)
```

after the package installation you can run `spam` as a standalone program in your terminal:

```sh
$ spam
eggs!
```

Read [this tutorial](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) for more info on command line scripts.

---

Now, if you want to execute custom code on testing, you have to override the default `test` command. In your `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools.command.test import test

class MyCustomTest(test):

    def run(self):
        print('>>>> this is my custom test command <<<<')
        super().run()

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'test': MyCustomTest}
)
```

Now you will notice an additional print when running tests:

```
$ python setup.py test
running test
>>>> this is my custom test command <<<<
running egg_info
...
running build_ext

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

---

**Edit**: if you want to run a custom bash script before executing tests, adapt the `MyCustomTest.run()` method. Example script `script.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo -n ">>> this is my custom bash script <<<"
```

Adapting `MyCustomTest` class in `setup.py`:

```py
import subprocess
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.test import test


class MyCustomTest(test):

    def run_some_script(self):
        cmd = ['bash', 'script.sh']
        # python3.5 and above
        # ret = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        # print(ret.stdout)

        # old python2 versions
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        ret = p.communicate()
        print(ret[0])

    def run(self):
        self.run_some_script()
        super().run()
```

Output:

```
$ python setup.py test
running test
>>> this is my custom bash script <<<
running egg_info
writing spam.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to spam.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to spam.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'spam.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'spam.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Can I have the values for the command class dict be a bash script instead of a python function? Or should I just make a function that calls the script?

Comment: @LiamPieri It should be a class that overrides the correct command class (custom test command should be a class that overrides class `test` from `setuptools.command.test` module, custom `build` command should be a class that overrides class `build` from `distutils.command.build` module and so on). Still, no one prescribes you what your command class _should_ do, so you can call any bash script from there. I will update the answer with an example shortly.

Comment: @LiamPieri check the updated answer, an example of running a bash script is added at the bottom, should now also be runnable with `python2`...

Comment: thanks! I'm having an a weird issue when it comes to implementing this however, it doesn't makes sense to me. I'm using 2.7 so my super has to take in args. So I call super with `super(MyTestClass, self)` but it throws this error at me `super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj`. Which doesn't make a any sense so I fed it in as `super(type(MyTestClass, self)` to which it spit back that self was not an instance of the type.

Comment: @LiamPieri interesting, didn't know this: [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698614/super-raises-typeerror-must-be-type-not-classobj-for-new-style-class). Add `object` to your interitance chain to fix the error: `class setupTestRequirements(test, object): ...` I don't do `python2.7`, thus not very much into its rules.