# Error by using super().Sub(n1,n2) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, super

I have this code:

```
class Operation:
    def Sum(self,n1,n2):
        SumResult=n1+n2
        print("Sum=",SumResult)
    def Sub(self,n1,n2):
        SubResult=n1-n2
        print("Sub=",SubResult)

class OperationWithMul(Operation):
    def Mul(self,n1,n2):
        MulResult=n1*n2
        print("Mul=",MulResult)
    def Sub(self,n1,n2):
        super().Sub(n1,n2)

def main():
    OpMul=OperationWithMul();
    OpMul.Sub(4,2)
    OpMul.Sum(10,15)
    OpMul.Mul(10,2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I run it I got an error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/path/OOPOverride.py", line
> 32, in <module>
>     if __name__ == '__main__':main()   File "C:/path/OOPOverride.py", line
> 24, in main
>     OpMul.Sub(4,2)   File "C:/path/OOPOverride.py", line
> 14, in Sub
>     super(Operation).Sub(n1,n2) TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

And when I put the mouse at the super() function it tell's me

```
> Python version 2.7 does not support this syntax. super() should have
> arguments in Python
```

So what is the correct syntax to use `super()` here?

Comment: Just a minor point but the exception message shows that you're not running the code that you have in the question. The code in your question uses `super()` while the traceback points to a `super(Operation)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698614/super-raises-typeerror-must-be-type-not-classobj-for-new-style-class). In Python 2.7 the function call to super needs the following arguments:

```
super(OperationWithMul,self).Sub(n1,n2)
```

And your root class needs to inherit from the object class:

```
class Operation(object):
```

In doing so, you define your class as a new-style class, which is the standard for Python 3.0 and comes with a range of advantages.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, you have to write it like this:

```
super(OperationWithMul, self).Sub(n1,n2)
```

Please refer to [`super()`'s Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2 to use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), you have to use new-style classes:

```
class Operation(object):  # makes the base-class a new-style class
    # your code

class OperationWithMul(Operation):
    # your code

# ...
```

And you have to pass in the current class and the instance explicitly to `super`:

```
super(OperationWithMul, self).Sub(n1, n2)
```

In Python 3 you won't have these problems because all classes are new-style and `super` infers the needed arguments. Even though it's probably beyond the scope of the question, you should really consider switching to Python 3.

Also method names in Python typically start with a lower-case letter. That's not a hard rule but it *could* make your code easier to understand for other Python programmers (like myself).