# using super() in python 2 raise type error

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class LinkFinder(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super(HTMLParser, self).__init__()
```

The code above receives the error:

```
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [super() raises "TypeError: must be type, not classobj" for new-style class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698614/super-raises-typeerror-must-be-type-not-classobj-for-new-style-class)

Comment: @Antwane it's not their class, it's from the standard library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html